# Container displayed incorrectly after install

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I installed `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` via NPM as described in the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/). After writing this little snippet, it does not work. It shows one `Col` below each other.

```
import React from "react";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 2</Col>
          <Col>2 of 2</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col>2 of 3</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default WetterWidget;
```

Is there anything I missed? Or lies the problem somewher else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your render() function should be inside a class called `WetterWidget`. Like this:

```
class WetterWidget extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 2</Col>
          <Col>2 of 2</Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>1 of 3</Col>
          <Col>2 of 3</Col>
          <Col>3 of 3</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```